# How can I see more questions displayed in my home page?

Tags: support, user-interface

Right now I can see 41 questions on my home page.

Since the questions appearing on my home page are the only one that are really interesting to me (because looking at the complete list of questions or browsing tags is really slow and not so efficient), how can I see more questions like that?

Comment: Does a RSS feed work better for you?

Comment: No, RSS are way too overwhelming and when I get one the question has already plenty of answers.

Comment: You can limit RSS's based on tags.  Also why do you want more questions if it gets too overwhelming?

Comment: RSS are overwhelming, and I cannot stop them from coming. I can F5 the page when I want instead, and in the home I can spot the questions I found most interesting much quicker, and playing with favorites tags. Questions on the home page are unbeatable. Would be really good to be able to have at least another page with 50 more.

Answer (score 4):

The front page's question count is a fixed limit of 50 (fewer if you have ignored tags hidden, though). It cannot be modified. Unfortunately, you will have to use the questions list as an alternative.